# Dynamically add and move Views in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-scrollview

I have the following layout:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollableContents"
    android:layout_above="@id/getting_started_buttons_container"
    android:layout_below="@id/getting_started_title_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/getting_started_keywords_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
    </FrameLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

In which i dynamically add views using a for loop in a container, i,m using translation to move them to right

```
 index = 0;
 for (Word word : wordList) {  //wordList size is 15 or more
        index++;
        view = new MyView(this, null);
        view.setTranslationX(index * 150);
        container.addView(view);
        container.invalidate();
        scrollView.requestLayout();
        scrollView.invalidate();
    }
```

My scrollView does not extend over the screen since it has the initial empty view. I need to see all views. Can anybody help me? I need a way to update scrollView to a width that contains all my elements

EDIT: I want to achieve something like these with a dynamically number of circles, which  must extend in scrollView if there is no room on the screen. LinearLayout is not a solution....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

replace RelativeLayout with horizontal LinearLayout

Comment: I need RelativeLayout or FrameLayout since I will make further translations on my views, and LinearLayout ruins my computations.

Comment: Can you explain me why RelativeLayout does not work?

Comment: I can't understand why LinearLayout doesn't work for you, but if you want to use RelativeLayout I think you need to change the width of it everytime you add a new View or add them in right/left of previous added View

Comment: I have edited my question, LinearLayout will broke my views since they will be moved next to each other

Answer (score 1):

you used RelativeLayout as parent view. Then you will need to use LayoutParam to add **Rules** for setting position like **toRightOf()** and **alignParentTop**.

If you don't add rules for your views, your views will be overlapped in same place (**Top and Left**)

So just use LinearLayout with orientation to be easy.

Thanks. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have edited my question, LinearLayout will broke my views since they will be moved next to each other